# <Future> fetch call returns instance of 'Snippet'

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried following the Future builder widget guide in the Flutter docs.

However, when I make the fetch call and try to display the information I get 'Instance of 'Snippet'.

I noticed that when I jsonDecode(res.body) it properly shows the JSON of the response but then after I run it through Snippet.fromJson and return it is when I get 'Instance of 'Snippet'.

Here is the code where I create the class and under it is where I call it.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class SnippetProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String snippetUrl = 'https://endpoint';

  Future<Snippet> getSnippets() async {
    final res = await http.get(snippetUrl);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      debugPrint('data: ${jsonDecode(res.body}'); //correct info 
      return Snippet.fromJson(jsonDecode(res.body));
    } else {
      throw "No snippets available";
    }
  }
}

class Snippet {
  final int book;
  final String title;
  final String list;
  final String body;

  Snippet({this.book, this.title, this.list, this.body});

  factory Snippet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Snippet(
      book: json['book'] as int,
      title: json['title'] as String,
      list: json['list'] as String,
      body: json['body'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

```
class _ShareState extends State<Share> {
  Future<Snippet> snippets;
  Future<Snippet> _future;
  var checkboxStatus = false;
  var snippetsToBeShared;
  final SnippetProvider method = new SnippetProvider();

  @override
  void initState() {
    snippetsToBeShared = new List();
    super.initState();
    snippets = pdfSnippets();
  }

  Future<Snippet> pdfSnippets() async {
    final data = await method.getSnippets();
    debugPrint('data: $data');
    //! this code breaks the app
    // data is an obj with nested objs
    // setState(() => {
    //       processedSnippets.add(data),
    //       processedSnippets[0]
    //           .map((snippet) => processedSnippets.add(snippet))
    //     });
    return data;
  }
        child: FutureBuilder<Snippet>(
          future: snippets,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  //* will have to hide the eccess snippet with overflow
                  //? and have a max width to fit the trailing checkbox
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('${snapshot.data.body}'),
                  subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data.title}'),
                  [...]
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] please? I see a lot of code that is commented out and on the other hand I see that you have left out code that you have. It's hard to say what's wrong if what we see is not what you run.

Comment: Printing a `Snippet` calls `.toString()` on the `Snippet`, but the `Snippet` class has no `toString()` override.  What do you expect to see?  If you want it to print JSON, then you will need to add a `toString()` override and do that yourself.

Comment: Ah I see, so what should I be returning from the `getSnippets` function in the `SnippetProvider` class in order to use that data to display it through the ListTile widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsonDecode parses the string and returns the resulting Json object. So you see the parsed Json object in debug console. And then you construct the Snipped object with fromJson(jsonDecode(res.body)) ,
you get the real Snippet obejct not the Json object. And you get 'Instance of 'Snippet.

Comment: Ah I see, so how do I get Snippet.fromJson to return an object instead of an instance?

Comment: above the class _ShareState extends State<Share> you should create an instance of snipped line Snapped createdSnipped  = new Snapped(); and then you get the value with getSnippets().then((value) => createdSnipped = value);